What does it mean for science if the universe isn't designed in a way that we can prove our theories correct?
[Complete rewrite of an earlier question. The system wouldn't let me submit it as an edit; I don't know why. Specific question at end.]
Before astrophysics, my first major was physical anthropology. Evolution so obviously occurred, that I truly wonder how it went unnoticed for so many centuries. I also can't stand religious people.
NEVERTHELESS:
The relentless drive to complexity looks like intent. The machinery inside a cell, that alone, should be "case closed." And if you stick a trillion of them together you can build a talking monkey, and see if he figures it out.
We have Erectus bones, and we have Habilis bones, but we don't have anything in between. Not a single one. It's like someone released version 2.0.
And how many individuals would have died if it weren't for their slightly receeded supraorbital torus? Two? One?
Yet that feature, and countless others, appears in every single version release, all at once, in the entire population.
I still feel ashamed to say it, but life at the molecular level is so obviously intentionally designed, that I really feel dumb denying it. I feel embarrassed watching Neil Degrasse Tyson and my hero, Dawkins, deny it.
I think evolution isn't magic; it's sufficiently advanced technology that's indistinguishable from magic.
Denying intent in evolution looks like ignoring the elephant in the living room when the tail is slapping you and everyone else in the face. More vertical forehead? WHAP! Wandering Foramen Magnum? WHAP!
Unless we're the first species to evolve in the universe, something else came before us billions of years ago. With that time to learn and understand, creating a new spacetime like a garden to see what would grow is just about the kind of thing you'd expect from them.
THIS STATEMENT APPEARS TO BE TRUE:
ID  may very well be true, and if it is, then science is deliberately excluding the true explanation, ad hoc, like the astronomers who refused to look through Galileo's telescope.
BUT SO DOES ITS CONTRADICTION:
But that matches the pattern of ancient people thinking that God's anger caused lightning. Believing ID is just as stupid. If we don't understand something yet, we can't just say "God did it!"
Like Godel, ID may provide us with a truth that is not provable within the system.
Another example is string theory. It explains all of quantum field theory and unifies gravity into a theory of everything, but we can't test it because the energy required to screw around with supersymmetric particles is WAY unachievable.
Yet, without that, this magnificent Opus becomes just another crackpot crank case aether theory.
MY QUESTON:
If there's really good evidence that something (e.g., ID or string theory) is almost certainly true, but we'll almost certainly never be able to prove it with hard evidence, is falsifiability still mandatory for belief?
[Sorry this is so long]

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

"ID may very well be true, and if it is, then science is deliberately excluding the true explanation, ad hoc"
This is a misrepresentation of science, that's commonly repeated by theists, especially creationists who reject the scientific consensus (commonly as part of them trying to explain why their view is so very unpopular among the many, many people who dedicate their life to studying the origin of life and the history of our planet).
Science doesn't "ad hoc" exclude supernatural explanations.
Science is merely (very roughly speaking) the process of investigating things that are consistently and repeatedly observable (or which has or had effects that are so observable).
When looking into the past, science is largely about tracing back chains of causation according to what we can find evidence for.
If the actions of a "supernatural" entity had effects that are directly or indirectly observable in the natural world, we can look at those effects and potentially draw the conclusion that that happened (but we haven't gotten to such a conclusion).
Let's compare this to a meteor impact
This is a one-time event, so it's not consistently and repeatedly observable directly. We may not have direct observation of it at all. It might have functionally come out of nowhere (e.g. it came from some untraceable place in the sky, and showed up suddenly and unexpectedly, right before shattering into undetectable pieces).
But still, we can conclude that meteor impacts happened, by looking at the consequences of impact. We can consistently and repeatedly observe the soil around the impact event, and we can take measurements and compare that to soil elsewhere, and we can simulate the effects of such an impact on the surrounding area, and take measurements to look for those effects.
For meteor impacts, we have direct evidence of other meteor impacts, so it wouldn't be directly comparable to some one-time action of a supernatural being. But we can still trace things back to that impact event, all the same.
We can see when something happened at some specific point in time, even if we've never seen anything quite like that before and even if we can't investigate beyond that (although science does require similarities on some level, at least).
This would also be true of the actions of a supernatural entity... but we just don't have evidence of such an event.
Science mostly just excludes things with no observable effects
... (or things which has effects that we can explain in simpler ways, with no lines of evidence making the more complex explanation more likely)
Science fundamentally can't investigate a deity that has never directly acted in reality, where reality is in every way indistinguishable from such a deity not existing (whether such a deity exists would be more a question of epistemology). But deities that actually do stuff - those can be investigated with science, via the effects of their actions.
And investigated we have. Young-Earth creationists say God created the Earth 6000 years ago, but every single scientific means we use gets us an age of billions of years instead. They say there was a global flood, but every scientific means we use suggests that no such thing happened, and creationists can't explain the fossil record. We've tested the efficacy of prayer, and found a lack of effect at best, and contrary effects at worst. Rather than accepting the failure of their claims, they've resorted to attacking the means used to investigate it, which we've used to accurately explain so much of the world. I'd guarantee that if science had validated their claims, they'd be shouting that from the rooftops, rather than holding their current position of science just not being able to investigate it, of needing to start with the presupposition of the Bible regardless of what science says.
What if there's really good evidence, though?
You ask what if there's "really good evidence" that ID is almost certainly true, even if it falls entirely outside of science.
But that premise is stretching plausibility.
Science is the best means we have of investigating empirical evidence, and science has a fairly broad scope in terms of what empirical evidence it can investigate. For your premise to hold, we'd either need empirical evidence that science can't investigate (but it's still "really good" evidence), or we'd need "really good evidence" that excludes empirical evidence. I don't see much reason to think either of those things can be true.
About evolution...

The relentless drive to complexity looks like intent.

There isn't a "relentless drive" to complexity. Today's complexity took BILLIONS of years to come about, and it's hard to wrap one's head around just how much time that is.
And we also like to focus on particular things that seem complex to us, even though (a) for every complex eye, there is some more much simple single-celled amoeba - there's a huge range of complexity, and (b) we have very strong evidence of many, many steps along the way, to get to that complexity, with corresponding reasons for why that complexity came about. The main driving force is natural selection, i.e. adapt or die. The species that didn't adapt, that didn't add some complexity where needed, didn't pass on their genes, so we don't see them living today.

life at the molecular level is so obviously intentionally designed ... Denying intent in evolution looks like ignoring the elephant in the living room when the tail is slapping you and everyone else in the face

Calling something "obvious" (and using an analogy of something that's obvious) is not an argument, and most molecular biologists disagree with you on it being designed at all, never mind it being so extremely obvious.

We have Erectus bones, and we have Habilis bones, but we don't have anything in between

I'm reminded of a Futurama scene:

Banjo: Oh! [He shows a hologram of a man and a chimpanzee, with a backwards prohibition sign running through an arrow.] If you elitist, East Coast evolution is real, why has no one found the missing link between modern humans and ancient apes?
Farnsworth: We did find it! [The arrow is replaced by Homo erectus.] It's called Homo erectus!
Banjo: Then you have proven my case, sir, for no one has found a link between apes and this Homo erectus. [The arrow is put between before Homo erectus.]
Farnsworth: Yes, they have! [The hologram fills in again.] It's called Homo habilis!
Banjo: Ah-ha! But no one has found the missing link between ape and this so called Homo habilis.
Farnsworth: Yes, they have! [The hologram fills in.] It's called Australopithecus africanus!
Banjo: Oh-ho! I've got you now! [Time Lapse. The hologram now shows 19 different species of ape. Only Fry and Leela are still there.] Fair enough, but where, then, is the missing link between apes and this Darwinius masillae? Answer me that, Professor!
Farnsworth: Okay, granted, that one missing link is still missing, but just because we haven't found it doesn't mean it doesn't exist!

The point is that we have strong evidence of human evolution, in the form of many points between primitive apes and humans, showing a slow incremental change over time. We have strong genetic similarity between humans and other apes.
Creationists typically then come along, picking 2 species right in the middle, and saying we don't have evidence of anything crossing that gap, even though:

It ignores all the steps leading up to that, and the steps beyond that
Those chosen species are already very similar
It's often the case that there's significant overlap in the physical structure of those species and related species
The various things people say defines a human came about in different species, so creationists either LIE about properties of some species to make their claim make sense, or they use ad-hoc reasoning to explain why what they call an ape has characteristics that they call human, and vice versa.

Human evolution is the thing creationists obviously have one of the strongest aversions to accepting, because it means that humans aren't some uniquely created species that's better than all the other animals. It rather undermines the idea that there's a god whose specifically made humans, and specifically made the world for us and specifically put us in charge of all of it, and specifically wants a relationship with us, and specifically cares about us, and wants us specifically to live with him forever. It also challenges the common egotistical idea that the world revolves around us, that we're not only the center of our own world, but the center of the world of everyone and everything else, too. But honestly, human evolution may be one of the parts of the origin of life that has the strongest evidentiary support. It was recent enough (relatively speaking) that we just have an absurd amount of fossils showing that transition.
Creationists want to deny that humans are apes, but there is not one single biological criteria they can use for this, that would separate humans and only humans, from the other apes, that wouldn't also result in also e.g. separating cats from one another, or separating dogs from wolves, which is contrary to what creationists say about their relatedness.

Unless we're the first species to evolve in the universe, something else came before us billions of years ago. With that time to learn and understand, creating a new spacetime like a garden...

This is mostly just a twist on the simulation hypothesis, and I don't find this compelling for the same reason I don't find that compelling (and why I don't find idealism or absent creator claims compelling): you're adding an entire model of reality that's completely unnecessary, for which we have zero evidence, with no explanatory or predictive power, and which we don't even know is possible.
Maybe life came about elsewhere in this unfathomably large universe. Maybe they died out. Maybe they had mass extinctions (like we did), but they didn't manage to continue on. Maybe they never got to human-level intelligent life. Maybe they're still living and thriving. But they are almost certainly far too far from us for us to ever find out about one another, never mind communicate or interact.
Is falsifiability mandatory?
No, falsifiability was never mandatory. Falsifiability can roughly be considered a part of reliability, i.e. it's some way to get our beliefs closer to being true rather than false. I might say reliability is "mandatory". At least if you care about truth, which I'd argue you should. If you care about truth, I can't think of much that's better than reliability. And falsifiability is one of the most reliable things - you can literally directly, and as objectively as possible, test whether something is true. That's the gold standard.



Are almost all scientists all across the world all lying to us because they're just too scared to tell the truth?
Well... no (to put it very politely).

Does abiogenesis + random mutation + natural selection explain life and the fossil record? The answer to this is clearly "no", as quite a few evolutionary biologists have implicitly admitted, even if they aren't willing to say so out loud ... no biologist could safely research this area; it would ruin his career

That's such a dishonest portrayal of evolutionary biologists as basically secret creationists, even though they clearly deny it. They try to explain this by scientists just being too scared to admit to that, because of the imaginary persecution narrative that theists like to perpetuate. This is despite most people still being theists, and theism having been much more common in the scientific community in years past, when these scientific theories gained widespread acceptance due to overwhelming evidence (which we've only gotten more of since then).
And this portrayal stands opposed to, you know, creationism just being pseudoscientific garbage, and evolutionary biologists actually being competent enough at their job to reach the conclusions best supported by the evidence (i.e. evolution), and them being honest about the conclusions they reach.
There is a lot to say with regard to epistemology about these types of conspiracy theorists, who make up these entire narratives in their head, about all these people who actually secretly believe things despite firmly saying the exact opposite, about this severe prosecution they face, and about some shadowy cabal keeping creationism out of science, even though none of that is in any way supported by the evidence. And they craft these narratives to make their preferred claims make sense. Rather than accepting that they just believe false things, and correcting their beliefs.
Also, let's not forget the tens of millions of dollars that's given to creationist organisations, where there are plenty of people trying to do scientific research to support their conclusions. And the result of all of that? ... Absolutely nothing. A big fat zero correct predictions. The best research creationists have done was to conclude that their own models don't make sense, without incorporating multiple miracles or needing entirely different models of physics, even though they can't explain what those are or how they work. The worst of creationist research (i.e. most of it), is rife with blatant misrepresentations of the evidence and of scientific studies and of what scientists say, as well as giant leaps in logic, cherry-picking, selective reasoning and just ignoring large amounts of evidence.
If the scientific consensus were so severely wrong as people like to claim, it would be baffling that those who oppose it has done such an extremely poor job of trying to show as much, without even one single thing that they can explain better than mainstream science can, despite the large amounts of money that's been thrown at them.


is falsifiability still mandatory for belief?

No, falsifiability is never required for any belief. Beliefs don't need any justification. Anyone is free to believe anything.
There is a long list of so-called pseudosciences here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_topics_characterized_as_pseudoscience and for each and every one if them, there are some intelligent and well educated believers.
Maybe some in the list are actually true, who knows, but surely NOT ALL.
Unless we want to think that all these pseudosciences are true, we are forced to agree that neither intelligence nor education are perfect protection against delusional thinking.
Falsifiability is a better protection against believing something that is false.
Anyone strongly believing in any of those so-called pseudosciences should investigate what makes them so different from any intelligent and educated believer in any of the other pseudosciences. While any human can fall prey to delusional thinking, there is a chance to correct false personal beliefs, and a way to understand the psychology of all these intelligent and educated people believing in all of the those pseudosciences that are untrue (if any are untrue).
So rather than trying to push ones own personal fringe beliefs, it would be beneficial to understand the psychology of others who push fringe beliefs.
In "the emperor's new clothes", it was not all of society who was deluded, it was just the emperor. Not everyone bought the invisible fashion.

Just want to remark that ID is on the Wikipedia list of topics characterised as pseudoscience... Though I missed last Thursdayism, one of my favourites.

Science doesn't claim to be perfectly correct. It claims only to be our best understanding at the time. New data is continuously appearing, and science adjusts to allow for that. We will probably never have proof that a theory is exactly correct... But as long as our ability to analyze and predict continues to improve, we consider that progress, and as a preponderance of evidence accumulates we accept that as our working theory.
If something is untestable, it isn't science, though it may become science once we find a way to test it. If we do not accept the possibility that we have made a mistake, or not accounted for all possible cases, that isn't science either.

What you perceive as “very good evidence” in my eyes seems to be coming from a pattern of reasoning that is self defeating. You look at the complexity of a cell and think “haha! Design!” and yet ignore the complexity of the potential designer.
Presumably, this designer would be more complex than the cell. Would this also make you go “aha! This is so obviously designed!”? If so, this leads to an infinite regress of designers, which for many reasons in philosophy, seems to lead nowhere.
If it doesn’t make you go “aha!” and you can imagine a very complicated god, or alien like being, existing without design, then why can’t you imagine a less complicated thing, like a cell, existing without design?
In other words, positing a designer who you can’t independently verify the existence of doesn’t explain anything. It creates more questions than answers. Positing an even more improbable thing to explain something improbable seems to me the height of irrationality.
All of this of course hinges upon the notion that the designer of the cell really is more complex than the cell. But to me, this seems intuitively obvious. How can the creator of a cell, that can create other things except the cell, especially a very powerful being who is conscious and has a will and has knowledge, be simpler than a cell? Almost no one would claim that a human is simpler than a book, or that a beaver is simpler than the dam it creates. The notion of “divine simplicity” that posits god as the most simple thing ever is to me an obvious farce but I realize that this is a debate in philosophy.

As I commented under another answer:I am afraid you didn't answer the question. We are to assume that ID has good evidence. Then the question is wether the lack of falsifiability is still mandatory for a justified belief in this theory.

If ID has good evidence, then there is no reason to deny it, so there is no need to worry about denying it. The questioner is either engaging in fallacy (which she is in my eyes given how she said it seems obvious the cell is designed) or asking an unrealistic question.

Well, maybe it is better not to answer unrealistic questions. I almost did the same in my urge to defend evolution theory. Then I realised that that was not the question.

The unrealistic question, if it is one, stems from fallacious reasoning that leads to her impulse to “obviously” see design in biology. The answer is meant to point that out.

Not answering the question, just taking an obvious ID bait.

You would have to question your method of determining a true scientific theory. If you cannot determine a theory of the events you observe then either those events are unexplainable or explainable by a divine theory you cannot comprehend. Logically!

Note that "cannot determine a theory" only proves failure to determine a workable theory so far. It does not prove that a theory will not be developed, or that it does not already exist but simply isn't one we are aware of. There is a huge difference between inexplicable and unexplained. Logically.

As Hume argued 300 years ago, it seems that the universe is set up so that we can't prove anything about nature that we have not directly observed. There have been many responses to this issue. Kant tried to prove that we can know about nature because the universe is something that is inherently intelligible. Various authors have argued that we can have probabilistic knowledge, although Hume's argument applies to probabilistic proofs as well. Popper, Khun and others have argued that in fact we can't know anything about nature.
As to life and evolution, these issues would be a lot less emotional if people could separate issues. Creationists are emotionally invested in the criticisms of evolution because they want to prove the existence of God, and anti-creationists are just as emotionally hostile to those criticisms because they are afraid that it might lead to God. They are both wrong. If you separate the issues properly they have no effect on arguments for or against God until you are well along in the process. Here is a sequence of issues:

Does abiogenesis + random mutation + natural selection explain life and the fossil record? The answer to this is clearly "no", as quite a few evolutionary biologists have implicitly admitted, even if they aren't willing to say so out loud. Their understanding of the intractable problems with this explanation has led to multiple attempts at additional mechanisms such as punctuated equilibrium, but they can't just openly say that the mechanisms taught in school are not enough because they would be accused of giving aid and comfort to the enemy (the creationists) and it would ruin their careers.

Is there an additional mechanism or set of mechanisms which could be added to those three to explain life as we know it? I'm using "mechanism" here to mean there is no teleological influence. That question could be an interesting field for further research, but research is hindered because biologists can't be open about what they are doing. They can't have conferences on the failures of current evolutionary theory or speculative discussions about what sorts of additional mechanisms might fill the gaps because they can't acknowledge the gaps. If creationists have a god-of-the-gaps problem, biologists have a silence-of-the-gaps problem.

Is there evidence of design? Note, I am separating concerns, here, so I specifically mean just evidence of design, not evidence of God. A lot of the gaps in evolutionary theory could be explained by ancient, advanced aliens, but that's kind of an extreme speculation. Before you can take that sort of speculation seriously, you need some quantifiable evidence of design beyond mere intuition that life seems to be designed. Again, no biologist could safely research this area; it would ruin his career.

If there is evidence of design, what is the course of design that has occurred? Can we explain certain organisms more simply by saying they have a designed combination of features from other organisms (not their ancestors)? Can we infer things about tools and methods? Can we narrow down exactly during what periods the designers would have had to be at work? (I've been toying with the idea of writing a science fiction book with the premise that a biologist studies this very issue and discovers that we are due to be visited by the creator aliens very soon.)

Assuming we decide that there is design and that we can learn something about how and when it happened, can the design be explained by natural beings?


It isn't until step 5 that there is really any danger from the God hypothesis, and frankly it's a minimal danger, so there is really no reason for people to react in such a hostile, panicky way to ID theory. Their attitudes are holding back research that might very well have put natural origins on a surer scientific footing if they had allowed the research to progress. But instead, they insist on stifling any research that threatens the status quo.

I am afraid you didn't answer the question. We are to assume that ID has good evidence. Then the question is wether the lack of falsifiability is still mandatory for a justified belief in this theory. The question is epistemic in nature. Your complaint that the scientific community is holding back ID research is flawed because ID does not provide a mechanism or testable predictions to explain how this "design" occurred. There is no research program.

@Philomath, you need the research program first. The testable predictions come from the research program. Preventing a research program so that you can continue to claim lack of testable predictions is not very scientific. And falsifiability is a boogeyman. What testable predictions does evolution make that have proven true and that were not already known to be true in Darwin's day?

There is a well funded institute: Discovery Institute's Center for Science and Culture. Surely they could've hammered out a research program by now? Possible falsfication of evolution: precambrian rabbit fossils.

@Philomath, the Discovery Institute is still on step one, discussing and publicizing what the biologists aren't willing to acknowledge: the deep failures of the current solution. Furthermore, they aren't allowed to publish in the journals that they would need to publish in to start a real scientific discussion. It is contemptible and unscholarly the way the insiders all conspire to prevent any progress in this area and then point to the lack of progress as a sign that the area is unscientific.

@trkruse, words like "incoherent", "whines", and "rants" betray that you are not interested in an impartial scholarly discussion. Simply by disagreeing with you, I have betrayed myself as the enemy and so you feel the need to attack me. All you are doing is proving my point about how anyone who disagrees with the status quo can't get a fair hearing.
